# Como forçar o dowload de um pdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma aplicação em PHP e HTML de um formulário de cadastro de inscrição, como faço pra fazer download de um select como exemplo: Ao clicar em sim, ele faz o download de acordo com um link que faz este (download) em pdf. Segue o print para maiores informações e o script também.`

```
<script>
  function carregaPdf(){
     if(document.getElementById("alojamento").value == "SIM"){
        window.open("http://www.ibc.gov.br/media/common/regulamento_interno_do_alojamento_ibc.pdf");
      }
   }
</script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Alojamento</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select onchange="carregaPdf()" class="form-control" name="alojamento" id="alojamento" style="width:100px; padding:2px;" required>
            <option value="">Selecione</option>
            <option value="SIM">SIM</option>
            <option value="NAO">NÃO</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Minha dúvida é que está abrindo uma janela com o pdf, quero que force a baixar o arquivo pdf assim que clicar em sim, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Cara, para te ajudar. Sempre poste o código aqui ao invés de colocar em um ambiente externo. Na verdade pode fazer isso, mas coloque o código aqui e se quiser pode deixar em outro lugar como pasteBin, CodePen ou JsFiddle. Agora... isso você vai fazer com JS. Ao selecionar a opção, poderá fazer um change no select.

Comment: Eu postei no Pastebin

Comment: @CarlosEduardoFerreira aqui não colocamos na pergunta como resolvido. Há sim um visto para marcar a resposta como certa, se for o caso.

Answer (score 1):

Poderá criar uma função change para receber o valor do combobox e fazer uma verificação de opção. Se escolher sim, redireciona o usuário para o link do arquivo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').on('change', function(){
      var valor = $(this).val();
     
      if(valor == 1){
         document.location.href = 'link-para-download.php'; // ou .pdf 
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">Selecione a opção</option>
  <option value="1">Sim</option>
  <option value="2">Não</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Pode, mas coloque aqui... Se tem a opção de colocar aqui, colocar aqui. Tem gente que não tem acesso a sites externos, apenas ao Stack.